# Microsoft Teams not sharing screen with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-teams

I tried the solution to disable Wayland in custom.config, received X11 as the server with a restart, not happening.
I am using the teams from Microsoft - latest version for X64 system.

Screen sharing not happening. With Wayland enabled, using Teams with the latest edge browser, only tabs can be share, selecting options like window, entire screen does not.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks
SKB

Comment: honestly, no. Teams is just the least useable-on-linux client of the large corporate videochat solutions (these being Teams, WebEx, and Zoom). Honestly, try with a modern google chrome and the web client. Sometimes features work in that that don't work in the desktop client and vice versa. It's not even consistent across different machines running the same Ubuntu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.